# Displaying two tables in a row in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How to add two tables in a row in **bootstrap**? [image]

As shown in the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Lpcu3so6/4/

You can use the class `row` in bootstrap and then divide your page like this :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <!--table1 -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <!--table2 -->
    </div>
</div>
```

This will give you two `div` with both occupying equal space. This is according [Bootstrap's Grid View System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic)

---

You can also try one thing : Design two tables and give both of them float left like this :

```
<div>
  <table style="float: left">
    <tr>
      <td>..</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="float: left">
    <tr>
      <td>..</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

or simply use css:

```
div>table {
  float: left
}
```